# How to work around the invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 ArgumentError?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to run the following code where I use nokogiri to parse an xml file. I want to eliminate new line characters from text
contained between  tags. The code I have here, used to work, but for some reason, now it doesn't. Possibly because I 
upgraded to ruby-1.9.1.

```
titles = node.search('b')
titles.each do |e|
  unless e.parent.name == "h4"
    if e.children.children.first.nil? == false
      puts e.children.children.first.text.gsub("\n","")
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
HI.  You're using libxml2 version 2.6.16 which is over 4 years old and has
plenty of bugs.  We suggest that for maximum HTML/XML parsing pleasure, you
upgrade your version of libxml2 and re-install nokogiri.  If you like using
libxml2 version 2.6.16, but don't like this warning, please define the constant
I_KNOW_I_AM_USING_AN_OLD_AND_BUGGY_VERSION_OF_LIBXML2 before requring nokogiri.

test.rb:35:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Are you willing not to follow the advice to upgrade?

Comment: Your really should follow the advice (to upgrade, not to hide the warning!) and then test your code again. If the error still exists, give a comment. By the way, you also should use Ruby 1.9.2 and not 1.9.1!

Comment: possible duplicate of [nokogiri not installing correctly for ruby-1.9.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182429/nokogiri-not-installing-correctly-for-ruby-1-9-1)

Comment: Where can I find the instructions for upgrading the ruby in Mac OSX? as far as I know I can only do it via RVM

Comment: It's probably not such a good idea to mess with Mac OSX's Ruby. I would go for MacPorts/Fink or maybe Homebrew instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing 1.9.2 via RVM.

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm install 1.9.2
```

If you want ruby to default to your rvm 1.9.2 install, then

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

NOTE: The above are equivalent to:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ruby=1.9.2
```